# RESTful java, проблема с ссылками

Tags: java, rest

Всем привет! Есть построенный Web Service на jax-rs 2.0. Проблема заключается в том, что не могу поставить правильно ссылку в Html странице на css стили. Кто может помочь с проблемой?[image: Вот как я указываю в html]

Comment: Что значит "не могу"? И что обслуживает статику?

Comment: "Не могу" означает, что каждый раз когда я ставлю какую то ссылку, оно не видит стили, и не знаю, что делать, что бы исправить это. Html страницы загружаются через web.xml.